# I want to make this code shorter is that possible?

Tags: python

I'm really interested if this code can be shorter/cleaner, because its looking like a mess.
Any help/ideas appreciated!

```
    data = re.sub(r' data-saferedirecturl="http\S+"', '', data)
    data = data.replace('<div dir="ltr">', '<p>')
    data = data.replace('<h4 dir="ltr">', '<h4>')
    data = data.replace('<h3 dir="ltr">', '<h3>')
    data = data.replace('<div>', '<p>')
    data = data.replace('</div>', '</p>')
    data = data.replace('target="_blank" ', '')
    data = data.replace('&nbsp;', '')
    data = data.replace('rel="noopener noreferrer" ', '')
    data = data.replace('href', f'title="{zoekwoord}, " href')
    data = data.replace(f'{domein}', '')
    data = data.replace('<p></p>', '')
    data = data.replace('href="https://', 'target="_blank" href="https://')
```

Comment: The "snippet" feature is for HTML/CSS/JS, not Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the patterns into a list of tuples, and then loop over them using unpacking:

```py
patterns = [('<div dir="ltr">', '<p>'),
            ('<h4 dir="ltr">', '<h4>'),
            ('<h3 dir="ltr">', '<h3>'),
            ('<div>', '<p>'),
            ('</div>', '</p>'),
            ('target="_blank" ', ''),
            ('&nbsp;', ''),
            ('rel="noopener noreferrer" ', ''),
            ('href', f'title="{zoekwoord}, " href'),
            (f'{domein}', ''),
            ('<p></p>', ''),
            ('href="https://', 'target="_blank" href="https://'),]

for p in patterns:
    data = data.replace(*p)
```

This approach will make it easier to manage the patterns.